# JQuery stops working

Tags: php, jquery

I have he following JQuery on my page and there is a form on it. After I select a name from the autocomplete function, it disables the mask and datepicker function.
Is there anything wrong on the code?

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("#name").autocomplete({
        source: "names.php",
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#name').val(ui.item.nome);
            complete_fields();
        }
    });
    $(".data").mask('99/99/9999', {
        placeholder: " "
    });
    $(".data").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        nextText: 'Next',
        prevText: 'Previous'
    });
});
```

Comment: should be `$(document).ready(function(){...`

Comment: What does `complete_fields()` do?

Comment: it completes ther other fields of the form via ajax... it calls a page and send the name via get.. the page searches the db and fills the fields with the information... should i post the code?

Comment: @GilbertoGonçalvesMachado Do the `.data` elements get replaced when that function is called?

Comment: yes... but i still declare the class on the new one..

Comment: The mask and datepicker are applied to the element. If you replace the element, the mask and datepicker are gone. After replacing the elements, you need to re-apply the mask and datepicker.

Comment: but on the new one i am applying the datepicker..